# Sonar issue for printStream constructor as "Remove this use of constructor" for PrintStream(outStream);

Tags: java, sonarqube, pkcs#11, csr, printstream

I am generating CSR using java code, I have taken the code from online website [journaldev.com](https://www.journaldev.com/)

```
public byte[] generateCSR(final String sigAlg, final PublicKey publicKey, final PrivateKey 
privateKey, final String organisationUrl) {

final ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outStream);

final X500Name x500Name = new X500Name("CN=" + organisationUrl);

final Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(sigAlg);

signature.initSign(privateKey);

final PKCS10 pkcs10 = new PKCS10(publicKey);

pkcs10.encodeAndSign(x500Name, signature);
pkcs10.print(printStream);

return outStream.toByteArray();
```

As you can see that above I have used printStream constructor, which takes ByteArrayOutputStream  as a parameter. Because of that sonar is saying not to use this constructor as that constructor will use default charset of the system, Anyone is aware that How can I resolve this?
I have tried as an alternative code :

```
final Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
final OutputStream out = new WriterOutputStream(writer,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
final PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(out, Boolean.FALSE, "UTF-8");
```

This code run, but it return an empty result. can you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to encode as UTF-8, replace

```
final PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outStream);
```

with this:

```
final PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outStream, true, "UTF-8");
```

You will also need to catch `UnsupportedEncodingException`.  This exception should never happen (because "UTF-8" is always supported) but you still need to catch it (or declare it) since it is a checked exception.

---

If you don't want the print stream to autoflush (i.e. the `true`), you could add

```
printStream.flush();
```

or

```
printStream.close();
```

before the `return`.  I suspect that the reason you didn't get any output with your clunky attempt at correcting the problem is that the data that `pks10.print` wrote was not being flushed to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.